# How do I find nullclines for an ODE given only one second order ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling

My textbook asks me to draw an outline of the phase space for $\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}-x\frac{dx}{dt}+x^2=0$ by studying the nullclines, but it never showed how to find the nullclines for a single equation like this, only with a system of equations. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Are you supposed to change this into a system of first order equations?

Comment: You can convert this into a system of equations by introducing $y=dx/dt$. Then the second derivative of $x$ can be replaced with the first derivative of $y$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint

Write your equation with a system...

$$\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}-x\frac{dx}{dt}+x^2=0$$
$$
\implies
\begin{cases}
x'=y \\
y'=xy-x^2
\end{cases}
$$